# Limit of alternating sum of factorial moments which diverge

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence, random-graphs

Consider the non-negative, integer valued random variable $X$, and its $i^{\text{th}}$ factorial moment $E_{i}[X]$. Then we have that
$$
P(X=0) = \sum _{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^i E_{r}[X]}{ i!}
$$
See e.g B. Bollobás *Random Graphs*, Corollary 1.13, where this is demonstrated.

If these moments diverge with some parameter $x$ (which they may well do if $X$ counts e.g. subgraphs of a random graph as the number of nodes goes to infinity), for example consider they look like
$$E_{i}[X](x) = \frac{ \left(3^{\frac{3 i}{2 i+4}} \left(x\sqrt{\pi } \right)^{\frac{i^2-3 i+2}{i+2}}\right)}{\sqrt{(i+2) 2^{i-1}}}$$

Then, to evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty} P(X=0)$, we would need the limit of the following alternating sum (I start from $i=2$ as these expressions are only contributions to the moments, but they are all similar. Another contribution will start from $i=0$).

$$
f(x) = \sum _{i=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^i \left(3^{\frac{3 i}{2 i+4}} \left(x\sqrt{\pi } \right)^{\frac{i^2-3 i+2}{i+2}}\right)}{\sqrt{(i+2) 2^{i-1}} i!}
$$

So, I am looking at $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$. Here is a plot of the sum and its partial sums.

[image]

It appears to be descending, and I know this is non-negative. So it is (in theory) going to zero, so long as it keeps descending?

The limit of the sum is difficult as most methods I can see don't involve sums of terms that diverge as $x \to \infty$. I can't swap the sum and the limit, for example, as one cannot with the limit of $e^{-x} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^i x^i}{i!}$.

The main idea I can see is to try and upper bound the sum, and show that upper bound goes to zero, but does that mean I need to "upper bound the even (and so positive) terms, and lower bound the odd (and so negative) terms"? Does anyone have any advice on how to calculate $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$?

Comment: Does your summation start with $i=0$ or $i=2$?

Comment: It might be easier to find $P(X=0)$ from a description of $X$ (what is it?) than from the series expression.

Comment: Also, you should replace $r$ by $i$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis $X$ is a path count between two nodes of a random graph. The factorial moments of the path count are composed of many terms, of which one sequence looks like this. Each term is a way in which an $i$-tuple of paths can overlap distinctly. The oscillating sum of these moments is the only way I can express this path-existence probability $P(X=0)$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis, basically for 3-hop paths, Chebyshev works as an upper bound on $P(X=0)$ (I have the mean and variance of the number of paths $X$, and $\mathbb{E}(X^2)/\mathbb{E}^{2}(X)$) goes to zero as the number of nodes go to infinity). But this isn't the case for 4-hop paths, so I need a more direct method involving a description of $P(X=0)$, and this one from Bollobas is the only one I can really see.

Comment: I don't understand "It appears to be descending, and I know this is non-negative.  So it is (in theory) going to zero".  Of course, even granted that the apparent decrease continues, a non-negative quantity can decrease but not tend to $0$!  Did you mean something more like "I conjecture that it is going to $0$"?

Comment: @LSpice So, even if the gradient remains negative for all x, and it never goes below zero, it can converge to something greater than 0? I suppose that's part of the questions. Thinking about it, if it converged to 0.1 then it would always have a negative gradient.

Comment: [Certainly](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431141/limit-of-alternating-sum-of-factorial-moments-which-diverge#comment1109805_431141); just consider something like, say, $f : x \mapsto x^{-1} + 1$.  On the other hand, if, for example, you know not just that $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x$ but that the logarithmic derivative $f'(x)f(x)^{-1}$ is bounded away from $0$, then $f(x) \to 0$.

Comment: Ok that is very useful, I have not seen the logarithmic derivative before! I will see if I can show that the logarithmic derivative is bounded away from zero for all x. Is there a theorem about this idea I can use?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431141/limit-of-alternating-sum-of-factorial-moments-which-diverge#comment1109815_431141), there's probably a name any analyst would recognise, but I don't know it.  [It](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431141/limit-of-alternating-sum-of-factorial-moments-which-diverge#comment1109812_431141)'s just using the mean-value theorem to observe that $\bigl(\ln(f)\bigr)'(x)$ negative and bounded away from $0$ implies that $\ln(f(x)) \to -\infty$.

Comment: I think it might help if you make your description of $X$ complete and precise. In particular, it is unclear what exactly you mean by "a random graph", "hops", etc. Also, $EX^2/E^2X$ can never go to $0$ (as you seem to suggest).

Comment: What I might do, is create a new question with all the details, carefully written, with the story so far. I think trying to summarize part of it ends up looking a bit confusing. This will involve a description of X, and the different definitions.

Comment: I'll do this by editing the question.